# ¿cómo puedo saber la diferencia entre tiempos h:i:s.v en PHP?

Tags: php

¿Cómo puedo saber la diferencia entre tiempos h:i:s.v en PHP? Tengo el siguiente código:

```
 $t1 = new DateTime('01:14:23.164');
 echo $t1->format('h:i:s.v')."_____";
 $t2 = new DateTime('now');
 echo $t2->format('h:i:s.v')."_____";
 //01:14:23.164_____01:14:50.882_____

 $diff=date_diff($t1,$t2);
 echo $diff;
 $t3 = new DateTime($diff);
 echo $t3->format('h:i:s.v');
```

Me gustaría obtener un resultado de esta forma (diferencia): 00:00:22.064

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Buen día,

El formato de la diferencia está mal, te hace falta utilizar `%` ([documentación](https://www.php.net/manual/en/dateinterval.format.php)), no hace falta crear un nuevo `DateTime()`.

Ejemplo:

```
 $t1 = new DateTime('01:14:23.164');
 echo $t1->format('h:i:s.v')."_____";
 $t2 = new DateTime('now');
 echo $t2->format('h:i:s.v')."_____";
 
 $diff=date_diff($t1,$t2);
 echo $diff->format('%h:%i:%s.%F')."_____";
?>
```

Comment: ¿porque en algunos momentos aparece un signo de -? así: 0:7:3.-196619

Comment: Si bajas un poco en la misma página que puse menciona eso, es un bug en versiones PHP <= 7.2.11 ([Referencia](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=77007))