# ¿cómo puedo saber la diferencia entre dos horarios con milisegundos?

Tags: php

¿Cómo puedo obtener la diferencia entre dos horarios con milisegundos exactos? Tengo el siguiente código: la variable $tiempo1 la obtengo de una base de datos.

```
  $t1 = new DateTime('$tiempo1');
  echo $t1->format('h:i:s.u')."_____";
  $t2 = DateTime::createFromFormat('U.u', number_format(microtime(true), 6, '.', 
  ''));
  echo $t2->format('h:i:s.u')."_____";



  $diff=date_diff($t1,$t2);
  echo $diff->format('%h:%i:%s.%u')."Resultado_____";
```

si pongo "%f" en lugar de "%u", si me aparece resultado, pero en algunos casos me arroja un signo de "-"(bug).  10:46:58.-418666

Comment: Buen día, [la respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/532555/171630) de tu pregunta anterior aplicaría para esta pregunta también, tal como dice la página que puse en la respuesta, el bug fue corregido y solo afecta versiones PHP <= 7.2.11. Lo que puedes hacer es utilizar PHP 8, o ¿Hay algún motivo por el que no puedas actualizar la versión?

Comment: @HeytalePazguato Muchas gracias. Ya revise y el servidor en donde estaba haciendo las pruebas, tiene una versión <= 7.2.11, pero el servidor donde estará el proyecto es 7.3